# Python boilerpipe installation issue

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, boilerpipe

I am trying to insatll [Python Boilerpipe](https://github.com/misja/python-boilerpipe) in my Ubuntu 14. It fails with the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 27, in <module>
    download_jars(datapath=DATAPATH)
  File "setup.py", line 21, in download_jars
    tar = tarfile.open(tgz_name, mode='r:gz')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1678, in open
    return func(name, filemode, fileobj, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1730, in gzopen
    raise ReadError("not a gzip file")
tarfile.ReadError: not a gzip file
```

These are the steps I am following:

- pip install JPype1
- pip install charade
- git clone
  https://github.com/misja/python-boilerpipe.git
- cd python-boilerpipe
- sudo python setup.py install

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the issue, so in the setup.py they are looking for boiler-pipe tar file. And they download it from googlecode, which is not there any more.

```
def download_jars(datapath, version=boilerpipe_version):
    tgz_url = 'https://boilerpipe.googlecode.com/files/boilerpipe-{0}- bin.tar.gz'.format(version)
```

So I replaced the same line with the new file location:

```
tgz_url='https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/boilerpipe/boilerpipe-1.2.0-bin.tar.gz'
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of any similar alternative for example try [jusText](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jusText/2.1.0)

```
pip install justext
```

Below are some alternatives:

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/webascorpus/?source=navbar
- https://github.com/jiminoc/goose
- https://github.com/grangier/python-goose
- https://github.com/miso-belica/readability.py
- https://github.com/dcramer/decruft
- https://github.com/FeiSun/ContentExtraction
- https://github.com/JalfResi/justext
- https://github.com/andreypopp/extracty/tree/master/justext
- https://github.com/dreamindustries/jaws/tree/master/justext
- https://github.com/says/justext https://github.com/chbrown/justext
- https://github.com/says/justext-app